# Spring bean configuration for Crud Repositories

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing an application which injects data to elastic search. Used spring-data-elastic-search jar to inject data.

```
 package com.customer;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;

    import com.customer.repositories.CustomerRepo;

    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    public class CustomerService {

        @Resource
        CustomerRepo custRepo;

        public void save(Customer cust) {
            custRepo.save(cust);
        }
     }
```

==================================================================================

```
  package com.customer;

    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;


    @Document(
        indexName = "Customer", type = "cust"
       )
    public class Customer{

        private String name;

        public Customer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

==================================================================================

```
  package com.customer.repositories;

    import com.customer.Customer;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

    public interface CustomerRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, String> {

    }
```

==================================================================================

```
 package com.customer;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class MainClass {  
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-customer.xml"});
            CustomerService cust = (CustomerService)context.getBean("customerService");
            Customer customer = new Customer("appu");
            cust.save(customer);
        }
```

## }

Spring-customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.customer" />

    <import resource="spring-repository.xml"/>

     <bean id="customerService" class="com.customer.CustomerService" scope="prototype" >
        <property name="custRepo" ref="custRepo"></property>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

==================================================================================

Spring-repository.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
    </bean>

    <elasticsearch:repositories
        base-package="com.customer.repositories" />
```

```
The issue is that, I'm getting the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at com.customer.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:438)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.MappingElasticsearchEntityInformation.<init>(MappingElasticsearchEntityInformation.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.MappingElasticsearchEntityInformation.<init>(MappingElasticsearchEntityInformation.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchEntityInformationCreatorImpl.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
```

It seems like some thing wrong with my bean configuration

```
 <bean id="customerService" class="com.customer.CustomerService" scope="prototype" >
    <property name="custRepo" ref="custRepo"></property>
 </bean>
```

CustomerRepository being an interface, how can I enforce spring to lookup the implementation classes automatically.

Note: This is working fine when container does the '**autowiring**' . But while initializing from bean xml file, the issue persist.

Can any one help to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not in your bean configuration but you have to declare @Id as below in Customer class

```
 @Document(
    indexName = "Customer", type = "cust"
   )
public class Customer{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //setters and getters

  }
```

You need to have Id in order to index an entity, SD elasticsearch does not support any entity to be indexed without an id.

## EDIT 1 :

==========================

You don't need to define service as bean and inject manually a repository into it.
Just mark it with @Service and use repository as @Resource as above

changes in your files

1) CustomerService.java
    package com.customer;

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.customer.repositories.CustomerRepo;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Resource
    CustomerRepo custRepo;

    public void save(Customer cust) {
        custRepo.save(cust);
    }
 }
```

2) spring-customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.customer" />

      <import resource="spring-repository.xml"/>

</beans>
```

I have not tested it but should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Mohsin. I've added @Id and while running got the following exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerService' defined in class path resource [spring-customer.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'custRepo' while setting bean property 'custRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'custRepo' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'custRepo' is defined
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)

Comment: I only added 'custRepo' as  ** ref="custRepo" ** I can't specify value,class configuration as it is an interface. Any suggestions ?

Comment: hey Spring guys, Any inputs. I need a solution urgently.

Comment: i have edited my answer. have a look , should work now. You don't need to define service as bean and inject manually a repository into it. Just mark your with @ Service and use repository as @ Resource.

Comment: Thanks You Mohsin. @Service addition solves the problem for me.