# Spring data elasticsearch CRUD configuration

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing problem while configuring the spring data elasticsearch, I followed the procedure mentioned here [Spring bean configuration for Crud Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132952/spring-bean-configuration-for-crud-repositories/29836442). But I am getting error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customerService': Injection of resource
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customerRepo': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property
>   'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path
>   resource [spring-repository.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Could not instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Here is the code:

CustomerService.java

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {
@Resource
CustomerRepo custRepo;

public void save(Customer cust) {
    custRepo.save(cust);
}
}
```

Customer.java

```
@Document(
        indexName = "Customer", type = "cust"
        )
public class Customer {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;

public Customer(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

CustomerRepo.java

```
public interface CustomerRepo  extends ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-customer.xml"});
    CustomerService cust = (CustomerService)context.getBean("CustomerService");
    Customer customer = new Customer("test_name");
    cust.save(customer);
}
}
```

spring-customer.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.elasticsearch" />

<import resource="spring-repository.xml"/>

</beans>
```

spring-repository.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="xx.xx.xx.xx:9200" />

<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
</bean>

<elasticsearch:repositories
        base-package="com.elasticsearch.repositories" />
```

I don't know why it is not working. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It worked finally, after modifying these files:

1) spring-customer.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.elasticsearch.repositories" />

<import resource="spring-repository.xml"/>
<bean id="customerService" class="com.elasticsearch.CustomerService" scope="prototype" >
        <property name="custRepo" ref="custRepo"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

2) Changing port no. from 9200 to 9300 in spring-repository.xml. As 9200 is for http, where as 9300 is for node to node communication.

3) Adding getter and setter for custRepo in CustomerService.java file.